# ASP ImageButton in Repeater not firing

Tags: asp.net, postback, repeater, imagebutton

I have a usercontrol that contains a repeater. Within this repeater there is an ImageButton, that when clicked is supposed to call an expand method. However, the ImageButton is not firing anything, not even a PostBack.

AutoEventWireUp on the usercontrol is set to true. the Repeater ItemDataBound is set in Markup. But even with all of that the ImageButton still will not fire any type of action.

What would be the reason that no firing is occuring at all?

Below is the HTML Markup:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" Codebehind="BiddersGroupList.ascx.vb"
    Inherits="FXWB.BidPackage.BiddersGroupList" TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="fxwb" TagName="GridLabel" Src="~/Secure/Controls/GridLabel.ascx" %>

<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="rcbScripts" runat="server">
<script>
      function pb(ctrl,FolderId, B, BID, CID)
      {
//        debugger;
        var lblid = ctrl.parentElement.parentElement.cells[7].childNodes[0].id;
        SethdnUpdatedValues(lblid, (B=='WB') ? 'Yes' : 'No');
      NoRefreshRequestProcessor_SendRequest('changeBidStatus:'+B+':'+BID+':'+CID);
      }

      function ir(ctrl,FolderId, BID, CID)
      {
        debugger;
        if(ctrl.checked ==true)
            B = '1';
        else
            B = '0';        
        NoRefreshRequestProcessor_SendRequest('changeAdminIsRceived:'+B+':'+BID+':'+CID);
      }

      function pw(BPID, SUID, FID){
      var BID ='Owner';
      window.open('Bidpackage/ReplyToBid.aspx?BPID='+ BPID + '&SUID='+SUID+'&BID='+BID + '&FID='+ FID + '&a=edit','_blank','height=600,width=800,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable = yes');
      }


      function be(BID, BPID,CSI){
      window.open('Bidpackage/EditBidderInfo.aspx?BidderID='+BID+'&BidPackageID='+BPID+'&CSI='+CSI,'bidder_edit','height=550,width=950,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable = yes')
      }

      function one(sender,NID,CsiValue,lblid){
      //debugger;
        NoteLabelID=lblid;
      var url = 'Bidpackage/BidderNoteEdit.aspx?NoteID='+escape(NID)+'&CSI='+CsiValue;
      var Top = (screen.availHeight / 2) - 100; //getY(sender) - document.getElementById('FolderBody').scrollTop + 226;
      var Left = (screen.availWidth / 2) - 150; //getX(sender) + 280;
      var params = 'height=200, width=300, location=0, top='+Top+', left='+Left+', status=0, scrollbars=0, toolbar=0';
      var arr=NID.split(':');
      window.open(url,'BDR_NOTE_'+escape(arr[0]),params);
      //window.open(url,'BDR_NOTE_'+escape(NID.replace(':','_')),params);
      //window.open(url,params);
      }



      function SelectAll(chkMain)
      { 
      //debugger;
      var mainchk = chkMain.getAttribute("Division");
        var chk = document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<chk.length; i++)
         {
            if(chk[i].type=='checkbox')
            {
             csiChild = chk[i].getAttribute("Division");
              if (csiChild != null)
              {
               if(csiChild == mainchk)
                        {
                            if(chkMain.checked == true)
                               {
                                    chk[i].checked = true;
                                    SelectCodes(chk[i])
                               }
                                else
                                {
                                    chk[i].checked = false;
                                    SelectCodes(chk[i])
                                }
                        }
              }

            }
            }

      }
       function SelectCodes(chkMain)
      { 
     // debugger;
      var mainchk = chkMain.getAttribute("CSI");
        var chk = document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<chk.length; i++)
         {
            if(chk[i].type=='checkbox')
            {
             csiChild = chk[i].getAttribute("CSI");
              if (csiChild != null)
              {
               if(csiChild == mainchk)
                        {
                            if(chkMain.checked == true)
                               {
                                    chk[i].checked = true;
                               }
                                else
                                {
                                    chk[i].checked = false;
                                }
                        }
              }

            }
            }

      }


function CheckAllBidders(chkMain)
      {
     // debugger;
        var mainCSI = chkMain.getAttribute("CSI");
        var csi;
        var csiChild;
        var bidder;
        var chkChildID;

        var chk = document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<chk.length; i++)
         {
            if(chk[i].type=='checkbox')
            {

//                chkChildID = chk[i].id;
//                s = chkChildID.indexOf(":");
                    csiChild = chk[i].getAttribute("CSI");
                      bidder = chk[i].getAttribute("Bidder");
                    if (csiChild != null && bidder != null)
                    {

                        if(csiChild==mainCSI)
                        {
                       // debugger;
                               if(chkMain.checked == true)
                               {
                                    chk[i].checked = true;
                               }
                                else
                                {
                                    chk[i].checked = false;
                                }
                         }
                    }
            }

         }

      }

var btnReloadExpandedID = '<%=ButtonReloadExpanded.ClientID %>';
var hdnExpandBidderID = '<%=hdnExpandBidder.ClientID %>';

var btnBindBiddingStatus = '<%=ButtonBindBiddingStatus.ClientID %>';
var btnBindNotes = '<%=ButtonBindNotes.ClientID %>';
var hdnNoteCSI = '<%=hdnNoteCSI.ClientID %>';
var hdnCSIId1 = '<%=hdnCSIId1.ClientID %>';
var hdnExpandCSIs = '<%=hdnCSIIs.ClientID %>';
var NoteLabelID;
</script>

<script>
function BindNote(csivalue1,note)
{
//    var ButtonBindNotes1 = document.getElementById(btnBindNotes);
//    var HiddenNotesCSI1 = document.getElementById(hdnNoteCSI);
//    HiddenNotesCSI1.value = csivalue1;
//    ButtonBindNotes1.click();

    document.getElementById(NoteLabelID).innerHTML = note;
    SethdnUpdatedValues(NoteLabelID,note);
}

function SethdnUpdatedValues(id,value)
{
//debugger;
    if (id!=undefined)
    {
        var hdnUpdatedValues = document.getElementById('<%=hdnUpdatedValues.ClientID %>');
        if(hdnUpdatedValues.value!="")
            if(hdnUpdatedValues.value.indexOf(id) !=-1)
            {
                var st = hdnUpdatedValues.value.indexOf(id);
                var end = hdnUpdatedValues.value.indexOf("|~|",st);
                var valToReplace = hdnUpdatedValues.value.substring(st,end);
                var valReplaceBy = id + "=" + value;
                hdnUpdatedValues.value = hdnUpdatedValues.value.replace(valToReplace, valReplaceBy);
            }
            else
                hdnUpdatedValues.value = hdnUpdatedValues.value + id + '=' + value + '|~|';
         else
            hdnUpdatedValues.value = id + '=' + value + '|~|';
   }
}

function SetUpdatedValues()
{
//debugger;
    try
    {
        var hdnUpdatedValues = document.getElementById('<%=hdnUpdatedValues.ClientID %>');

        if (hdnUpdatedValues.value != "")
        {
            var values = hdnUpdatedValues.value.split('|~|');
            var ctrlValue;
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<values.length-1;i++)
            {
                ctrlValue = values[i].split('=');
                document.getElementById(ctrlValue[0]).innerHTML = ctrlValue[1];
            }
        }
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
    }
}






</script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DynamicLayout="true">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div style="background-color: White; position: absolute; z-index: 10; left: expression((this.offsetParent.clientWidth/2)-(this.clientWidth/2)+this.offsetParent.scrollLeft);
            top: expression((this.offsetParent.clientHeight/2)-(this.clientHeight/2)+this.offsetParent.scrollTop);">
            <img src="../Images/LoadingIcon.gif" height="80" width="150" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePannel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <%--<script type="text/javascript" language=javascript>
    function ShowData()
{
        var trValues = document.getElementById('<%=trRptrDivision.ClientID %>');
        trValues.style.visibility="visible";
}
    </script>--%>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnUpdatedValues" runat="server" />

        <script language="javascript">
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
            function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
            {

                SetUpdatedValues();
            } 
        </script>

        <asp:Label ID="lblTestStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <input type="button" id="ButtonReloadExpanded" runat="server" style="display: none;"
            value="Reload Expanded" />
        <input type="button" id="ButtonBindBiddingStatus" runat="server" style="display: none;"
            value="Bind BiddingStatus" />
        <input type="button" id="ButtonBindNotes" runat="server" style="display: none;" value="Bind Notes" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnExpandBidder" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnNoteCSI" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCSIId1" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCSIIs" runat="server" />
        <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background: skyblue; border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px; border-color: black;" width="100%" id="tblBiddersList">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="True"
                        EnableViewState="False" Font-Names="Arial"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptdivision" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" OnItemDataBound="rptdivision_ItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="MasterHeader">
                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonExpandCollapse" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" Text="Expand All" CssClass="button"
                                CommandName="ExpandCollapse" />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Divisions
                        </td>
                        <td class="MasterHeader">
                            Divisions Description
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="background-color: #66cc99;">
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="chkDivision" biddercount='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.countBidders")%>'
                                runat="server" onclick="javascript:SelectAll(this);" />
                            <%--  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDivision" runat="server" onclick="javascript:SelectAll(this);" />--%>
                            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ImageButton1" CommandName="ExpandDivision" ImageUrl="~/Secure/Images/plus_big.gif" />
                            <asp:Label ID="lbDivisionName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.classifier_name")%>'></asp:Label>
                            <%--                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfcgroup" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.csigroup")%>' />--%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.classifier_description")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="trup" id="trRptrDivision" runat="server" style="background: white;">
                        <td>
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rptrBidPackage" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptrBidPackage_ItemCommand">
                                <%--<HeaderTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="MasterHeader">
                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonExpandCollapse" runat="server" Text="Expand All" CssClass="button"
                                CommandName="ExpandCollapse" />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; CSI Code
                        </td>
                        <td class="MasterHeader">
                            CSI Description
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>--%>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr class="trup" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; height: 0%; display: none" id="trMaster"
                                        runat="server">
                                        <td class="tdupMaster">
                                            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ImageColapseExpand" CommandName="Expand" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CSIValue")%>'
                                                ImageUrl="~/Secure/Images/plus_big.gif" />
                                            <b>
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkCodes" biddercount='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.countBidders")%>'
                                                    runat="server" onclick="javascript:SelectCodes(this);" />
                                                <%--   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCodes" runat="server" onclick="javascript:CheckCodes();" />&nbsp;--%>
                                                <asp:Label ID="LabelCSI" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CSIValue")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </b>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="tdupMaster">
                                            <em>
                                                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CSIDesc")%>
                                            </em>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="trup" id="trRptrBidders" runat="server" style="background: white; display: none">
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            <table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="background: #eeeeee;">
                                                <asp:Repeater ID="rptrBidders" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" OnItemDataBound="rptrBidders_ItemCreated">
                                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <tr style="background: #cccccc; color: #205f7d; font-weight: bold; font-size: x-small;"
                                                            class="DetailHeader">
                                                            <td class="DetailHeader" align="right">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkSelectAll" runat="server" onclick="javascript:CheckAllBidders(this);" />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="DetailHeader">
                                                                Action
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="DetailHeader">
                                                                Company name
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="DetailHeader">
                                                                Contact
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="DetailHeader">
                                                                Phone
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="DetailHeader">
                                                                Fax
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="DetailHeader">
                                                                Email</td>
                                                            <td class="DetailHeader">
                                                                Will Bid</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <tr class="trup" runat="server" id="trBidder">
                                                            <td rowspan="2" style="width: 50px;" id="tdCheckBox" align="right">
                                                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIsReceived" Text="+" Font-Bold="true" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkBidder" runat="server" />
                                                                <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnFaxStatus" value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FaxStatus")%>' />
                                                                <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnIsReceived" value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.IsReceived")%>' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td rowspan="2" style="width: 0%;">
                                                                <img style="margin: 0px;" onclick="pw('<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BidpackageID")%>','<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.SiteUserID")%>','<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FolderID")%>');"
                                                                    src="Images/tool_preview.gif" alt="View"></img><img style="margin: 0px;" src="Images/BidPackage/tool_bidder_edit.gif"
                                                                        alt="Edit Bidder Info" onclick="be('<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BidderID")%>','<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BidpackageID")%>','<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CSIs!2!CSI")%>')"></img><img
                                                                            style="margin: 0px;" src="Images/BidPackage/tool_approve_f2.gif" alt="Will Bid"
                                                                            onclick="pb(this,'<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FolderID")%>','WB','<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BidderID")%>','<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CsiID")%>');"></img><img
                                                                                style="margin: 0px;" src="Images/BidPackage/tool_decline_f2.gif" alt="Will Not Bid"
                                                                                onclick="pb(this,'<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FolderID")%>','NB','<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BidderID")%>','<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CsiID")%>');"></img><asp:CheckBox
                                                                                    ID="chkIsReceived" ToolTip="Admin IsReceived" runat="server" FolderID='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FolderID")%>'
                                                                                    Checked='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.AdminIsReceived")%>' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="fn">
                                                                <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnBidder" value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BidderID")%>' />
                                                                <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnCsiID" value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CsiID")%>' />
                                                                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Organization")%>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="fn">
                                                                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FullName")%>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="fn">
                                                                <nobr>
                                                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Phone")%>
                                                </nobr>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="fn">
                                                                <nobr>
                                                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Fax")%>
                                                </nobr>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="fn">
                                                                <nobr>
                                                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.EMail")%>
                                                </nobr>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="fn">
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblWillBid" runat="server">
                                                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.WillBid")%>
                                                                </asp:Label>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr id="trBidderNote">
                                                            <td colspan="6" style="font-size: xx-small; background-color: #FEFEFE; padding: 0px;">
                                                                <span id="spanBidderNote" runat="server" class="Note">Note:</span>&#160;
                                                                <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnBidderNoteID" value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BidderNoteID")%>' />
                                                                <div style="height: 100%; width: 210px; border: solid 0px gray; display: inline;"
                                                                    id="note">
                                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblBidderNote" runat="server">
                                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BidderNote")%>
                                                                    </asp:Label>
                                                                </div>
                                                                &#160;&#160;&#160;
                                                                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Qualifications")%>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:Repeater>
                                                <%--                                <asp:GridView ID="GridViewBidders" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" Visible="false">
                                </asp:GridView>--%>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your repeater is inside the update panel so use trigger of async type like follow:

```
<Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imagebtn" EventName="CLICK" />
    </Triggers>
```

And make some changes in repeater's code...

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ImageColapseExpand" onclick="ImageColapseExpand_Click" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CSIValue")%>'
                                            ImageUrl="~/Secure/Images/plus_big.gif" />
                                        <b>
```

Create a click event in code behind like bellow:

```
protected void ImageColapseExpand_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Hope this will work for you......

Comment: The purpose of this button is to expand or collapse the repeater items within the parent repeater item. With the ImageCollapseExpand_Click wont that limit me from doing such as thing?

Comment: it was not your question ... no its doesn't matter where you are doing code of that.. when you once come on code behind you can do the code where ever you want.. if you want to manage it with item command then you also need to write the same code there... so its much better to use button the place of item command.. according to me.. i dont know what the other perfecter's opinion on this.